# Python didn't show output in terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
#list

ok=["apple", "orange", "mango"]
print(ok)
```

This is my code in vs studio code, i want to print that list but it didn't showing any output when it run.

Is it a wrong thing in my code when i type?

Comment: Do you have both in one line? You can use backticks in Stack overflow to create codeblocks with the right indentation.

Comment: Is your code formulated as its displayed? it should work.

Comment: How are you running the code? If you add some other print, does it get executed?

Comment: Attach image of your VS code console before and after running the code. A complete screenshot would be nice to have.

Comment: >Karo answer: I haven't know it yet, but can you show me an example, i do like to know.

Comment: >jonh answer: yes it just like what i type above

Comment: >matszwecja: Yeah it didn't executed when i print another str

Comment: @MuhammadShamshadAslam No. Do **not** attach images. That's very much frowned upon in this place

Comment: @kiet Then the code you're running isn't what you're showing here

Comment: How would you see what is issue without having a look at the console? Based on the problem it looks like it has something to do with VS code settings. @DarkKnight ?

Comment: thank for you guys asking, i probally found out why it not executed, i type a function above list code that print(str) when it take input, it not executed any below code only when i type input.